# in require.js is there way to have common dependencies added globally and define more specific dependencies locally

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have a backbone/ marionette app - and on every js file I define what i need backbone, underscore myApp and then whatever template view controller i need like this

```
define([
'myapp', 
'backbone', 
'underscore', 
'text!fixtures/imports.json', 
'models/delivery'], 

function( 
myApp, 
Backbone, 
_, 
importsJson, 
DeliveryEntity 
)
```

What I would prefer is to have some of the things that are repeated on every file added as a group like

```
define(['common',
```

followed by the more specific dependencies

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? If not, then what problem did you run into?

Comment: well i couldn't find of a way to include it in the require documentation..  I was asking to see if there was a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
common.js
define(['underscore', 'backbone','myapp'], function(_, Backbone, MyApp){
  return{
    'Backbone': Backbone,
    '_': _,
    MyApp': MyApp
  }
});

main.js
require('common', function(Common) {
   // Common.Backbone
   // Common._
});
```

Comment: ok will try and let you know.. this seems like its going to work

Comment: this does not work! it gives a require error. I am thinking if i have to include a js library globally I would just have to hardcode it in the index.html which kinda solves my issue!